# What's wrong with the way I read image data from ICO files?

Tags: java, file, bitmap, io, ico

I am currently trying to write my own implementation of an ICO file reader.

And yes, I do know that it is possible using already existing libraries, this is not an option though.

Essentially, I got my reader to work up until the point of image data deserialization. Icon Directory Entries seem to be loaded correctly, but the image data in the `.ico` file I am trying to read "doesn't work".

First of all, here's the files related to this question:

- tested `ico` file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/sj579gdv0g60t3w/test.ico
- the raw bytes of the first `bmp` in it: http://www.mediafire.com/file/jr4xkbqvzpelozo/debug.bmp (corrupt file)
- full deserializer code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40a02094e8ad38dfc339bd144c6061e8

The method in question that does not properly work is this:

```
private static BufferedImage readImage(InputStream stream, IconDirEntry entry) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("deserializing "+entry);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[entry.data];
    stream.read(bytes);
    if (!isPNG(bytes)) {
        byte[] bmp = makeBitmapFileHeader(bytes);
        bytes = PrimArrays.concat(bmp, bytes);
    }
    return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
}
```

Basically, my approach is checking whether the image data bytes are a PNG and if not, concatenating them with a new header.

This way I can still use `ImageIO` to read the bitmap instead of having to make my own bitmap deserializer.

**When running the code, the icon directory entries seem to be loaded correctly and are printed into the console:**

```
IconDirEntry{dims=16x16, palette=0, planes=0, bpPixel=32, data=1128, offset=86}
IconDirEntry{dims=32x32, palette=0, planes=0, bpPixel=32, data=4264, offset=1214}
IconDirEntry{dims=48x48, palette=0, planes=0, bpPixel=32, data=9640, offset=5478}
IconDirEntry{dims=64x64, palette=0, planes=0, bpPixel=32, data=16936, offset=15118}
IconDirEntry{dims=128x128, palette=0, planes=0, bpPixel=32, data=67624, offset=32054}
```

Through all kinds of debugging I have verified that the header does have length of 14 bytes as it should, that the first bytes of the image data array look like a BMP info block etc.

I have also verified that the EOF is reached exactly when all the bytes amounts specified in the icon directory entries are loaded.

Also, the offset in the first `IconDirEntry` seems to be correct, since an `ico` header has a size of 6 bytes and each of the 5 `ICONDIRENTRY` blocks have a size of 16 bytes. (`6 + 5*16 = 86)`

Everything from `net.grian` packages has been tested and is proven to work, the error can not possibly lie there.

**Despite everything seemingly working, I am getting the following exception when loading the very first image:**

```
java.io.EOFException
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:353)
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:405)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read32Bit(BMPImageReader.java:1353)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read(BMPImageReader.java:890)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at me.headaxe.imtu.io.DeserializerICO.readImage(DeserializerICO.java:103)
    at me.headaxe.imtu.io.DeserializerICO.fromStream(DeserializerICO.java:54)
    at me.headaxe.imtu.io.DeserializerICO.fromStream(DeserializerICO.java:27)
    at me.headaxe.imtu.io.DeserializerICO.fromStream(DeserializerICO.java:18)
```

**All I really need is a hint as to why the image data can not be loaded correctly despite the rest of my code working flawlessly.**

(the raw bytes consisting of the "artificial" bmp header + the image data from the ico file are provided for download above)

#### UPDATE:

When I read exactly 960 more bytes than necessary when loading the first bmp in the ico file, I am no longer getting an `EOFException`, instead the first bitmap gets loaded and looks like this:
[image]
Due to that offset the second bitmap will obviously fail to load with an `IIOException` since it is malformed.

#### UPDATE:

Direct comparison between the `16x` ico and the malformed bmp:
[image]

#### UPDATE:

Printing all byte arrays before trying to deserialize them as Bitmaps yields the following results:
[image]
**This suggests that the amount of bytes being buffered is correct**, since they all begin with the iconic `40`, which is the length if the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure.

#### UPDATE:

Used a different `->ico` converter this time, effect stays the same in the sense that buffering more than the `data` field specifies produces an actual `bmp` file:
[image]
Bytes are: `[40, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 35, 46, 0, 0, 35, 46, 0 ...`
Since the `32` should be the image width and the `64` should be the image height, I am seriously confused since the ico is a `32x32` one.

In the second test, the `.ico` file is 4286 bytes large.
The first and only `ICONDIRENTRY` has an offset of `22` and data of `4264`.

**Despite that being perfectly correct and the correct amount of bytes being allocated, reading the bmp fails.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private static BufferedImage readImage(InputStream stream, IconDirEntry entry) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[entry.data];
        stream.read(bytes);
        if (!isPNG(bytes)) {
            setLittleInt(bytes, 8, entry.height);
            byte[] bmp = makeBitmapFileHeader(bytes);
            bytes = PrimArrays.concat(bmp, bytes);
        }
        if (DEBUG_FILE.exists() && entry.width == 32)
            new SerializerByteArray().toFile(bytes, DEBUG_FILE);
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    }
```

All that was required to make it work is line #5.

Apparently you can't rely on bitmaps stored in `.ico` files not to be corrupted garbage, so manually correcting the byte array fixes the "problem".

I have no words for this, I am completely dumbstruck.
Well, if anyone has an explanation for why such a thing would possibly fix it, please comment.

If anyone wonders, this is `setLittleInt`:

```
    private static void setLittleInt(byte[] bytes, int index, int value) {
        byte[] ins = IOMath.toBytes(value);
        bytes[index+3] = ins[0];
        bytes[index+2] = ins[1];
        bytes[index+1] = ins[2];
        bytes[index] = ins[3];
    }
```